# Swagger YAML - Map key must be unique

Tags: yaml, swagger

I am trying to render multiple path using `$ref`.

```
...
tags:
  $ref: "tags.yaml"
paths:
  $ref: "../register/paths.yaml"
  $ref: "../admins/paths.yaml"
```

But this doesn't work and throws an error -

`Map keys must be unique`

However, I have also tried it to do it like this -

```
...
tags:
  $ref: "tags.yaml"
paths:
  $ref: 
    - "../register/paths.yaml"
    - "../admins/paths.yaml"
```

But this also doesn't work.

How can I make it work to read multiple files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swagger 2.0 duplicated mapping key parser error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48254910/swagger-2-0-duplicated-mapping-key-parser-error)

Comment: Well I did come across that while looking for the solution but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any documentation saying only one `$ref` is allowed in each object, but apparently, not one example shows it is possible to have multiple `$ref` in one object.

For your use case, I assume you want swagger to extract all the paths in `paths.yaml`, it is not possible and you must define the paths directly under the `path` parameters, then write the documentation directly or by using `$ref`.

An example below:

```
paths:
  /debug/test: 
    $ref: ./api/Debug/test/config/api.yml
  /somefunction:
    $ref: ./api/SomeFunction/api.yml
```

`./api/SomeFunction/api.yml`
The 3 functions are located at the same level with `./api/SomeFunction/api.yml`

```
get:
  $ref: getFunction/config/api.yml
put: 
  $ref: setFunction/config/api.yml
post: 
  $ref: addFunction/config/api.yml
```

`./api/SomeFunction/getFunction/config/api.yml`
For the example get function, so as the put and post functons

```
  summary: "a get function to get something"
  description: ""
  consumes:
  - "application/json"
  produces:
  - "application/json"
  responses:
    "200":
      description: "Successful operation"
    "201":
      description: "Fail operation"
    "500":
      description: "server error"
  security:
  - petstore_auth:
    - "write:pets"
    - "read:pets"
```

The result is:
[image]